# Grouping three columns and then comparing the value if the fourth

Tags: r, dplyr, dummy-variable

I am working on election data through the years 2008 - 2017. I have proceeded with the analysis to an extent. However I am asking the following question.

I need to determine if a particular party has won the election in a particular constituency if it had won in the previous round of election.

The ST_CODE, AC_NO and YEAR (State Code, Constituency Number, and the Year) uniquely determine an observation. The fourth column is the name of the party which won for a given year.

```
ST_CODE YEAR  AC_NO PARTYABBRE
 S15 2008    21        IND
 S15 2008    22        NCP
 S15 2008    23        INC
 S15 2008    24        INC
 S15 2008    25        UDP
 S15 2008    26        UDP
 S15 2008    27        INC
 S15 2008    28        IND
 S15 2008    29        INC
 S15 2008    30        UDP
 S15 2008    31        INC
 S15 2008    32        INC
 S15 2008    33       HPDP
 S15 2008    34       HPDP
 S15 2008    35        INC
 S15 2008    36        INC
 S15 2008    38        NCP
 S15 2008    39        NCP
 S15 2008    40        NCP
 S15 2008    41        INC
```

A part of the dataset has been shown to give an idea. The year continues until 2017

So if party A won the election in 2008 in a specific ST_CODE and AC_NO, i would want to know if they have won the elections in 2013 (5 years later) If this is the case, then a dummy variable 1 should be added, otherwise 0

Answer (score 0):

We can `arrange` the data by `ST_CODE`, `AC_NO` and `YEAR`, `group_by` `ST_CODE` and `AC_NO` and use `lag` to compare the values of current year with the previous one.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(ST_CODE, AC_NO, YEAR) %>%
  group_by(ST_CODE, AC_NO) %>%
  mutate(previous_win = as.integer(PARTYABBRE == lag(PARTYABBRE)))
```

This will return `NA` for first year in each `ST_CODE` and `AC_NO` and will return 1, 0 for the next years.

Comment: I was looking at some form of this. However, I am not able to get around the fact that I need to assign 1 to the previous round of elections. In other words, exactly opposite to what you suggested.

Comment: @KaustavDutta In that case, use `lead` instead of `lag`. Replace last line with `mutate(previous_win = as.integer(PARTYABBRE == lead(PARTYABBRE)))`

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. And that piece of information saved me the agony. Thank you!